# What are the implications of turning the MDS off

Tags: 2013, mds, minimal-download-strategy

What are the implications of turning the MDS off.

Reference: http://www.wictorwilen.se/the-correct-way-to-execute-javascript-functions-in-sharepoint-2013-mds-enabled-sites

Answer (score 1):

Since I wrote the article you're refering to feel obliged to answer.

There are pros and cons of turning off MDS.

**Turning off MDS cons**

- You can't take advantage of the partial download, possible slower downloads and more bytes to download
- the user experience might suffer sine each page load takes longer time

**Turning off MDS pros**

- easier to create customizations (but read the article referred to and you shalt fear no more)
- nicer looking URLs

Comment: Yes I have read your article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104(v=office.15).aspx#bk_examplePersonPropsObj I am implementing a program from this link and it works occasionally and I feel it may be due to the MDS. Here I have posted my question also: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93968/error-while-accessing-the-user-profile-properties-via-js-code

Comment: Can you give me some advice on making my code work with MDS?http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93968/error-while-accessing-the-user-profile-properties-via-js-code

Comment: The code works amazingly superb and smooth flow of pages if MDS is turned off

Comment: Is there anyway that I can make my script MDS compliant?